# Avoid layout shift when changing font weight

Tags: html, css

I have a POC that will cause a layout shift only when a certain word is hovered, but I can't figure out why / what exactly is causing the shift.

If I hover the `Three` text, the layout will shift; while hovering any of the other elements won't cause a shift.

I know it has something to do with the `display: flex` of the div, but I can't figure out why is it causing the shift.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  font: 120% system-ui;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
a:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav>
    <a href="">One</a>
    <a href="">Two</a>
    <a href="">Three</a>
    <a href="">Four</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Why is it happening and how can I avoid it, without removing the `display: flex` from the div?

Comment: The `nav`s width is `auto`, is now and inline item (flex-child) and expands when hovered due to font change. Since it is now wider there is more room to share out per each `fr` and so layout shifts

Comment: I think your best option is to use transform: scale(1.3) instead of font-weight: 900

Comment: @Paulie_D but why does it happen only when I hover over "Three"?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova this is not answering the question about why this happens. It's also a very dirty "solution".

Comment: Probably because it's so much longer than the others, the proportionate increase is that much larger.

Comment: The reason is happening is quite obvious, "Three" is the longest world, so it needs more space than the others. As you want all columns to be the same width they are all assigned the width of "Three" and thus have a bit of space for when the text becomes larger. When "Three" is resized, it doesn't have that extra space, so it grows and all other columns have to grow with it

Answer (score 0):

Bold text is wider than normal text, so if your layout is tied to the width of some text, swapping it from normal to bold will potentially result in layout shift.

**Option One**

Detach your layout from the width of your text. Make your columns wider than your anchors.

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 3em);
  gap: 1rem;
  font: 120% system-ui;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: 200ms;
}

nav a:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">One</a>
  <a href="">Two</a>
  <a href="">Three</a>
  <a href="">Four</a>
</nav>
```

**Option Two**

Don’t change the font weight on hover. Change something else instead.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  font: 120% system-ui;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: 200ms;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #d70000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">One</a>
  <a href="">Two</a>
  <a href="">Three</a>
  <a href="">Four</a>
</nav>
```